# Windows 7 image to Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I just bought a Macbook Air and installed Oracle VirtualBox on it.  I have a Lenovo laptop with Windows 7 on it that I took a system image of it (Control Panel -> Backup and Restore -> Create a system image) on an external hard drive.  I would like to have this system image on the VirtualBox, but I'm having trouble.  On the external harddrive there seems to be two different VHD files (one is 4.4 mb and one is 50.3 gb in size).  I do not see an ISO file on the external harddrive.  When I created the new virtual machine and selected the 50.3gb vhd file as the virtual hard disk, I received the "Fatal boot: Int 18" error.  Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas how I can get this to work?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 7 backup image is not intended to be bootable by all accounts. You will need to restore the image. [Acronis](http://kb.acronis.com/content/3648) appears to be able to restore the image to a partition, if you dont want to write 50 Gb to DVDs.

> the backup VHDs are not bootable in the form they are created with
>   Windows backup.

[Reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6594c2da-1ce2-4139-8a07-21e6bdeb78fc/boot-a-windows-7-image-backup-form-win8?forum=w8itprovirt)